# Regex expression statement pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract values from the following statement using Regex , the statement looks like this: `from JFK to IND` So, I need to be able to extract `JFK` and `IND`

Can you help in providing the right regex expression for it?

Comment: I guess `/(JFK).*(IND)/` wasn’t working for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from\s+(?<origin>[A-Z]{3})\s+to\s+(?<destination>[A-Z]{3})
```

Answer (score 0):

^from ([A-Z]{3}) to ([A-Z]{3})$

the values you want will be in the two capture groups.

I can't elaborate any more unless you specify what language you are using the regex's in?

Comment: Always assume the best, not the worst. If querents can’t be bothered to state their restrictions, assume the best of all possible worlds.